# PostgreSQL - order randomly, but with NULLs first

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that takes all rows out of a table, and joins with another table I am updating. The other table has some items that have been checked (these get a value), and some which are not yet checked. I am trying to implement a way to update all records, but make sure any NULLs get sorted as quickly as possible. I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_stats
ON post_stats.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY RANDOM() NULLS FIRST LIMIT 10
```

However, this is ordering everything randomly. Is there a way to order everything randomly, but any NULLs get shown first?

Comment: `random()` will never return a `NULL` value, so `ORDER BY RANDOM() NULLS FIRST` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't even specify which column can contain NULLs in your query. This is an indicator that something is going wrong.

The following query (replace  with what you need) should do what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_stats ON post_stats.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY <YOUR_COLUMN> IS NOT NULL, RANDOM()
LIMIT 10;
```